# how Can i fetch the next in rank in php?

Tags: php, mysql

**I can't get the correct query for selecting the next in rank.**

Here is my query below:

```
$query2  = "SELECT implement_id, total_implement, percent, FIND_IN_SET( percent, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent
ORDER BY percent DESC ) 
FROM goal_implement )
) AS rank 
FROM goal_implement WHERE percent > (SELECT percent from goal_implement LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY percent ASC LIMIT 1
";
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I'm sure you understand what your query is *supposed to be doing*, but not everyone else does.

Comment: You cannot ! you are limiting the query result to 1. Check your parenthesis , looks like your applying limit to the full query. 
Agreed with Gordon hard to know what should return the query anyway.

Comment: for example sir, the current user have 70% then rank at 5th place.... How can i display the row on 4th place???

Comment: besides giving the SQL you have, try giving the the whole picture so others can help. Why do you have to query user 1 by 1? Where in the SQL did you use the information of "current user", is current user always at the top of goal_implement? Could you simply change the structure of the table to include a RANK column and update it accordingly?